# Provide more details and explanations about the different types of blocks in user profiles

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

Moderators see an additional section in a user profile that shows if a user is blocked from asking, answering, reviewing or editing. The information we can see is just yes/no in most cases.

The issue with this display is that it is extremely hard to interpret, especially now that data now that [the rolling question rate limits are enabled network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243460/rolling-question-rate-limits-are-now-network-wide).

The main reasons why it is hard to interpret is that the mechanisms behind it are secret, and multiple different mechanisms are hidden behind a single yes/no indicator. For example, I can't see if a user is permanently question banned or simply throttled at this moment. Then there is this "limited to 1 question per week" indicator that I misunderstood until an SE employee explained to me what it actually did (hint: it isn't an indicator if a user is simply hitting the rolling rate limit).

While we don't need this information very often, it would be quite useful to be able to actually understand it in some cases. If a user is already blocked, it might make further moderator actions unnecessary. Another reason would be that we moderators could give feedback to SE if it appeared that the blocking algorithms are either too strict or too lenient on our site.

What I'd like to have are the following improvements:

- tooltips or links to mod-only documentation about what each of the indicators actually means
- rate limits should be shown explicitly, not just yes and no
- different mechanisms shouldn't be combined into one indicator without making clear which mechanism is responsible for the block
- suspensions shouldn't appear as an answer block, of course they can't answer, but this hides if they have an actual answer block and is horribly confusing if you don't know this.

Comment: I'd also like to see an analogue "how banned are you?"-o-meter to figure out if someone is on the cusp or irretrievably banned.