# Maximum question limits? Or just rolling?

Tags: discussion, rate-limiting

Are rolling limits the ONLY limit on all SE sites now? In other words, has the maximum of 50 questions for every 30 days (previously on ELU and Maths) been repealed?

I read [Rolling question rate limits are now network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243460), but remained confused due to the lingering presence of posts submited before this change.

Comment: Your question is probably answered at [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/262755).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rolling rate limits mentioned in that question only pertain to the question blocking algorithms that stop users from continuing to ask questions that are being poorly received.

It had nothing to do with the monthly question limit, which is still in place and [serves a completely different purpose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89230).

Comment: Really?  People can ask 50 questions in 30 days without getting blocked?

Comment: I have asked 19 in the last 4 days. I'll comment here again if I'm not allowed to ask any more once I reach 30.

Comment: @Tim That monthly restriction only applies to Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault, and Math SE at the moment.

Comment: @Robert very rare on Stack Overflow, majority of users are blocked by downvotes after few questions.

Comment: @animuson ahh okay then. I won't be commenting back then ;)