# Why do answers not offset 50 question ban limit?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I'm experiencing the [50 question ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89217/173448) on Stack Overflow. I recently took over project maintenance for a popular project, and I had quite a few questions. (I think this is the first time I hit the ban).

I understand 50 questions is a lot, but I also contribute back to the community with answers. (Worse, a dozen or so are due to Git and its [inability to achieve the second goal of version control: determine differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31108960/tell-git-to-stop-prompting-me-for-conflicts-when-none-really-exist)).

I can't delete some of the obscure questions because they have answers. I'm not sure this is a good decision in general because it deprives future visitors of the information (but I would do it so I can ask my next question).

Why do answers not offset 50 question ban limit?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This isn't a punishment or implication that you're not pulling your weight; it's a rate-limit. There are similar rate-limits that apply on a daily basis as well. There are even rate-limits for answers.

As a general principle, allowing an action to be unlimited is asking for trouble. In this specific case, questions *used to be* unlimited, and... [there was trouble](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/02/new-question-answer-rate-limits/).

Over the years, the limits have been refined and adjusted: lots of folks hit the per-day limits, while very few hit the per-month ones - generally, once folks slow down a little bit they realize they don't need to ask as many questions as they thought they did. Before the limits existed, this realization was less frequent.

Deleting the questions wouldn't alter this either; it's a hard limit on how many can be *asked* in a given time period. It *is* a sliding window however, which means this isn't as dire as it seems: one month ago today, you asked three questions; by tomorrow, you'll be comfortably far away from hitting the limit again.

Comment: Regarding *"... allowing an action to be unlimited is asking for trouble"*: Would using contributions to offset the number for the ban move the issue back into unlimited or "near unlimited"? (I understand its a hard problem, and one size does not fit all).

Comment: You're describing [rolling rate limits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243460/rolling-question-rate-limits-are-now-network-wide), @jww, which control a *much* more restrictive limit.