# Weekly and monthly review statistics

Tags: support, review

You can only review 20 close votes per day.

[image]

Yet I've reviewed 90 posts this week, while the maximum should have been 3•20=60. Similiarly,  I've reviewed 162 posts this month, while the maximum should have been 4•20=80. In fact, the only day in this month, but not in this week, was August 1. It looks like I have reviewed 72 close votes on that day.

Looking into my review history, I actually never crossed the threshold. It is just that the stats are off. It happens at all users.

This is happening to all users on Math.SE, and also in all queues. I can't access enough data on other sites to decide whether it happens there as well.

Comment: Isn't that figure just the last 7 days for the week and the last 30 days for the month?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I verified you are correct. Please post that as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this context, "week" refers to the last seven days and "month" refers to the past 30 days.  This does not take into account partial weeks/months that occur as artifacts of our calendar system.

This "last 30 day" definition of month is similar to the [rolling question limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243460/300875) that are already in place.