# Area for reviewing and refining questions (Question Content Sandbox)

Tags: feature-request, new-users

After some of my questions were voted down, I really think we could all benefit by a 'test area' for questions ([not just the formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39109/is-there-a-sandbox-to-post-test-questions?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

In the suggested area, the user asks a question,  those who answer or comment help refine the question so that it will have a high probability of being voted up, not down. I know this would have saved me a lot of trouble - right now I am 'in danger of being banned' (temporarily) for reasons that could have been easily avoided if I had recveived some guidance earlier on.

Comment: Are you talking about chat?

Comment: I like this actually. Not all users access chat, and in reality, since it introduces a new UI, most of the users are reluctant to use it. People don't use meta either, since it's too much like the main site and they fear getting downvoted. The only problem here is that this is a bit vague, and anyway would require considerable dev time.

Comment: No not chat, and as for dev time, simply open up another community like 'physics' to say 'Refine your questions' or something like that . It will be just like all the other areas here. Maybe a topic for Area 51?

Comment: This idea was floated in 2014; it [didn't go far](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268779).

Comment: Are you proposing a 'test area' per site, or a network-wide 'test area'?  Please clarify this via an [edit] to your question rather than a comment.

Comment: How would a question in a 'test area' end up in a live site?

Comment: I have concerns about this proposal that include who would volunteer their time there, and the type of arguments that would result when a question that graduates the 'test area' gets closed or downvoted on a live site.  I think it is far more efficient to insist that new users take each site's Tour, and learn quickly how to ask a good question by paying attention to, rather than taking umbrage at, downvotes and close votes.

Comment: Network - wide test area. An alternative would be to either have a link to 'sample good and bad questions' and also to direct new users to the help site.  Or maybe suggest chat. Bottom line is, for experiencers of downvoting - we need help.

Comment: I sometimes wish there was something like an "extended tour" that led to a site-specific page with content like this one at GIS: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115

Comment: That's already in action on Stack Overflow, known as "Triage". I guess it can, in theory, be expanded to other sites as well.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's not Triage. IMO what the OP asks for is more like the Help & Improvement queue. Or rather, what the H&I queue was supposed to be.

Comment: @S.L.Barth oh, I might have confused between the two. You mean [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287466/help-improve-the-help-improvement-queue), but still - it's part of the overall project started in the dupe I linked to, as far as I can tell - helping new users get a better chance. And this one also can, in theory, be put in other sites.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Fair enough. I don't want these queues enabled on other sites though - too many unsolved issues surrounding them. Most reviews that I see in H&I neither help nor improve. We should either fix that queue, or ditch it and replace it with something else.

Comment: Marked as duplicate? Ok, I am now reading the duplicate question, and will get back to you.  My workaround is to refine my question in Meta, for example see http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7745/is-this-question-too-broad

Comment: Sorry, in the time that passed since this question was asked I came to understand it's not duplicate. Reopened now.

Answer (score 3):

It wouldn't make sense to have a global question sandbox, because evaluating questions requires the expertise of the community on which you want to ask the question.  Stack Exchange has more than 170 sites; this is an area where they can't all mingle together.

Some individual sites do have sandboxes -- [Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/34639), [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/640/28), and [Puzzling](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5276), at least.  As with the formatting sandbox here on Meta.SE, a per-site sandbox consists of a question (that describes the rules) where each answer is a draft of a main-site question that the author wants feedback on.  People interested in helping review new answers to this question and provide feedback in comments.  When the question is ready or the author decides it won't work, the answer is deleted from the sandbox.

How do people find out about new posts to review if there's no review queue lighting up on the main site?  Active meta users will see the post being bumped by new answers, but you can also feed new sandbox posts into the site's chat room.  (Worldbuilding does this.)  If neither your meta nor your chat room is active, getting attention will be more of a problem, but that would probably be true of a review queue too.