# 40 minute re-post limit bug

Tags: bug, asking-questions, rate-limiting

I signed up for Video.SE with two questions to ask. Asked my first, no problem. Tried to ask my second about 15 minutes later, but it informed me that:

> You can only post once every 40 minutes.

Sounds fair. However, my [first question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/18897/trading-off-resolution-vs-quality) was nearly 90 minutes ago, and I am still getting this error.

Ironically, I can't post to meta.video because of the same error, so I post here...

Bug?

Comment: Are you on a shared IP? Like a school/university?

Comment: @Oded OP here was able to post shortly after posting here, about two hours after posting the first question on that site. Maybe the [network wide rate limit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243460/rolling-question-rate-limits-are-now-network-wide) kicked into action? (and the message is off due to it)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - that's kinda what I am hoping to determine.

Comment: I was using the wifi at a cafe. However the cafe was nearly empty and I couldn't see any other laptop users. The problem persisted again for at least an hour after I posted above, then I gave up.

Comment: But you did post the second answer, hour after posting here. /cc @Oded see OP reply.

Comment: I did? I was talking about questions. I only see one question on V.SE : http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/18897/trading-off-resolution-vs-quality . Where is my second question?

Comment: @Oded I've just had the same problem on German.SE and couldn't ask about it on its Meta so I came here and found this question. Has anyone found a solution for this problem?

Comment: @Montag451 - posts means *either* questions or answers. This time limit is by design, as a spam protection measure.

Comment: To be clear, the time limit wasn't working as designed since I was blocked from posting on V.SE for several hours.