# Broken timer? "You can only post once every 40 minutes."

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, usability, rate-limiting

Recently, I asked my first question on retrocomputing.stackexchange.com .

I later attempted to ask a second question there, but when I clicked the "Post Your Question" button, a `div` element with a red background appeared, containing the error message, "*You can only post once every 40 minutes.*" However, this was more than *60* minutes after my first question, so the error message did not seem to make sense.

It turned out that the error message was missing some [pertinent information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide). It did not make clear that although the timeout only applied to the current site (e.g. retrocomputing.SE), the "40 minute" timer is measured from the user's most recent question asked *anywhere* on the Stack Exchange network. The absence of this information risks the user continuing to post elsewhere within the Stack Exchange network (as I had done), unaware that each time they do so, this would restart the timer and thereby extend the timeout arbitrarily, resulting in a negative user experience.

To fix the discrepancy between the error message and the actual behaviour, either the timeout code should be re-written to match the error message, or the error message should be re-written to correctly communicate to the user how the timeout works.

*Related: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306651/you-can-only-post-once-every-40-minutes-on-my-first-post?rq=1), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281240/40-minute-re-post-limit-bug?rq=1).*