# When will Stack Overflow remove my ban?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

Some months ago, I got banned from asking a question on Stack Overflow, because I was new and asking non-programming related questions on that site. So Stack Overflow banned me. Now if I try to ask a question, Stack Overflow shows me this message:

> You have reached your question limit Sorry, we are no longer accepting
> questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

I read [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) on Stack Exchange, and it says: "The only way for the ban to be lifted is by contributing positively to the site in other ways."

When I got banned my reputation was 34, but now to remove this ban I am contributing positively to the community by answering question, editing and flagging them. Now, my reputation is 800+, I have contributed enough. **How much more do I need to contribute to remove this ban?** I have also edited my previous questions, but the ban is still there. Is there anything wrong with Stack Overflow's algorithm? Or are all my contributions a waste?

Comment: [You can refer my this answer to know how to get out of question ban](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34043/876009)

Comment: First, know bans are imposed automatically. No humans are involved. Similarly, the ban can only be lifted automatically; no human can lift your ban manually. The algorithm fundamentally looks at how well your posts are received by the community, in terms of up/down votes, closures (for questions), deletions (for Q or A), etc. Beyond that, specific details (like score thresholds, etc) of the algorithm are not public, lest people try to find clever ways to evade bans. Bringing that all together means that *no one can tell you* when the ban will be lifted. You need to attract upvotes.

Comment: Your deleted questions are almost certainly dragging you down.  Answers affect question bans very little, and I'm not sure if edits do at all.

Comment: (That said, since you’re Q-banned but your score has increased, that must me you are contributing by posting answers. That’s great, and it will help. But it also means it worth pointing out to you that one, albeit vague, detail we do know about Q-bans is that it takes [“quite a few” well-received answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243460/rolling-question-rate-limits-are-now-network-wide) to get out of.)

Comment: As your link notes: "If you're blocked from asking questions and are unable to improve your existing questions (or your existing questions are all deleted), you'll get the chance to post one new question 6 months after your last question."

Comment: Thanks , so that means, the only option I have is that 1 question asking chance after 6 months.

Comment: Like the duplicate says: "To avoid bypassing the filter, its internal rules are a secret". No one will be able to give a more precise answer and tell you how much more you have to contribute.

Comment: The worst case is a half year. Undeleting your self-deleted, negatively scored posts (after working on them) will help. Possibly also writing a lot of well-received answers will help.